# fscanf from text file to struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to read from a text file to a struct that has a pointer to another struct.

The text file has the following format:

```
279288151 1 John Doe
002 1 30 04 2018
23189842 0 Jane Doe
0
282676381 1 Mark Examp
001 0 28 03 2018 03 04 2018
243897574 1 Joe Soap
003 2 14 04 2018 21 04 2018
```

This is my .h file:

```
#ifndef Clientes_h
#define Clientes_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Alugueres.h"
#define ST_TAM 50


typedef struct info_cliente Cliente;

struct info_cliente{
    char nome[ST_TAM];
    long nif;
    int n_alugueres;
    int n_hist;
    pAluga aluguer;
};

typedef struct aluga Aluguer, *pAluga;
typedef struct data DataIn, *pDataIn;
typedef struct data DaraEn, *pDataEn;

struct aluga{
    int id_unico;
    int estado;
    pDataIn dataIn;
    pDataEn dataEn;
    pAluga prox;
};

struct data{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

Cliente* le_fich(char *nome, int *n);

#endif /* Clientes_h */
```

And my read_file func is as follows:

```
#include "Clientes.h"

Cliente* le_fich(char *nome, int *n){

    FILE *f = fopen(nome, "r");
    Cliente *aux;
    int conta = 0;

    if(!f){
        printf("Error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    while(getc(f) != EOF){
        aux = (Cliente*)malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
        fscanf(f, "%ld %d %49[^\n]", &aux[conta].nif, &aux[conta].n_alugueres, aux[conta].nome);
        if(aux[conta].n_alugueres != 0){
            fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d", &aux[conta].aluguer->id_unico, 
            &aux[conta].aluguer->estado, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->dia, 
            &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->mes, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->ano);
        }
        conta++;
    }
return aux;
}
```

It gives me a bad_access error when trying to run the fscanf after the if is successful (when accessing the pointer of the struct for my date). If anyone could help me out, would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cyclonecode I do know when I create the file, but I'm supposed to determine the value once I get to the end of the file. If I put an malloc at the beginning of the loop, would that solve the problem, and then access the different fields with pointers?

Comment: `while(getc(f) != EOF){` loses the first character of the file, a `'2'`.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred should also be output.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );` which is created just for this purpose

Comment: regarding: `aux = (Cliente*)malloc(sizeof(Cliente));` 1) the returned type from any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text of why the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: strongly suggest replacing: ` while(getc(f) != EOF){
        aux = (Cliente*)malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
        fscanf(f, "%ld %d %49[^\n]", &aux[conta].nif, &aux[conta].n_alugueres, aux[conta].nome);`  with: `char buffer[1024]; while( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, f ) { call malloc() then use sscanf() to extract fieldsL  &aux[conta].nif, &aux[conta].n_alugueres, aux[conta].nome)`

Comment: the access error is because the field: `pAluga aluguer   is a pointer, so suggest replacing the pointer in the struct `Cliente` with an instance of the struct `aluga`

Comment: the posted code fails to tie all the heap allocations together, either by a linked list or by defining an array of pointers (that gets realloc'd with each new read data record.) then setting the individual pointers to be what is currently called `aux`

Answer (score 1):

Right now you allocating memory for `aux` in the loop and then try to access an element using an index which will not work. Instead you need to allocate memory for all `Cliente` records. If you know the number of records in the file you could simply do `aux = (Cliente*)malloc(size * sizeof(Cliente));`. You might also check on how you can use [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) in the actual loop.

Answer (score 1):

> It gives me a bad_access error when trying to run the `fscanf` after the `if` is successful

2 problems:

1. As [@Rishikesh Raje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50100096/2410359), [@Cyclonecode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047662/cyclonecode) pointed out, the allocation is only good for `aux = aux[0]` as well as other missing allocations.
2. The usual suspect to scanning problems are that the `fscanf()` did not scan what was expected and code lacked checks of the return value.  (Hint: when line is only `"0\n"`, the 2nd `fscanf()` reads more than OP expected.)

   ```
   ret = fscanf(f, "%ld %d %49[^\n]", ...);
   if((ret ==3) && (aux[conta].n_alugueres != 0)){
       fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d", ...
       // code errantly does not check the return value of `fscanf()`.
   }
   else {
     break; // This code missing, what to do when `ret != 3`
   }
   ```

---

A simply solution to both problems to (re)allocate as needed and check success of reading 2 lines and scanning them.

I recommend to not allocate data for the new pair of lines until the input have been validated.

```
Cliente *aux = NULL; // Initialize to NULL
size_t n = 0;    // Keep count of record count
char buf1[150];  // Use generous buffers.  Suggest 2x maximum expected need
char buf2[100];

// while 2 lines successfully read
while (fgets(buf1, sizeof buf1, f) && fgets(buf2, sizeof buf2, f)) {
  // Form objects to be scanned into with default values.
  struct info_cliente cli = { 0 };
  struct aluga alu = { 0 };
  struct data dat = { 0 };

  if (sscanf(buf1, "%ld %d %49[^\n]", &cli.nif, &cli.n_alugueres, cli.nome) != 3) {
    perror("Unexpected 1st line");
    break;
  }
  if (cli.n_alugueres == 0) {
    if (sscanf(buf2, "%d", &alu.id_unico) != 1 || alu.id_unico != 0)) {
      perror("Unexpected 2nd line 0");
      break;
    }
  }
  else if (cli.n_alugueres == 1) {
    if (sscanf(buf2, "%d %d %d %d %d", &alu.id_unico, &alu.estado, &dat.dia,
        &dat.mes, &dat.ano) != 5) {
      perror("Unexpected 2nd line");
      break;
    }
    alu.dataIn = malloc(sizeof *alu.dataIn);
    *alu.dataIn = dat;
    cli.aluguer = malloc(sizeof *cli.aluguer);
    *cli.aluguer = alu;
  } else {
    perror("Unexpected 2nd line n_alugueres");
    break;
  }
  Cliente *tmp = realloc(aux, sizeof *aux * (n+1));
  aux = tmp;
  aux[n] = cli;
  n++;
}

Cliente *tmp = realloc(aux, sizeof *aux * (n+1));
aux = tmp;
aux[n] = NULL;  // NULL terminate the list
```

**Note** Error checking on `malloc()`/`realloc()` omitted for brevity on the above sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **both** `getc` and `fscanf` to access the file.

If you want to use `fscanf`, you should not use `getc`.

Use the return value of `fscanf` to let you know when the file has ended. `fscanf` will return the number of items matched. In your case if successful it should return `3`.

```
int ret;
do{
    aux = (Cliente*)malloc(sizeof(Cliente));
    ret = fscanf(f, "%ld %d %49[^\n]", &aux[conta].nif, &aux[conta].n_alugueres, aux[conta].nome);
    if((ret ==3) && (aux[conta].n_alugueres != 0)){
        fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d", &aux[conta].aluguer->id_unico, 
        &aux[conta].aluguer->estado, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->dia, 
        &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->mes, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->ano);
    }
    conta++;
}while (ret == 3);
```

Comment: Instead of `aux = (Cliente*)malloc(sizeof(Cliente));`, consider the simpler `aux = malloc(sizeof *aux);`

Comment: `aux[conta]` will be invalid memory after the first iteration. It needs something similar to `aux = realloc(sizeof(aux[0]) * (conta + 1));` (which requires `aux` to be initialized to `NULL` before the loop).

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(f, "%d %d %d %d %d", &aux[conta].aluguer->id_unico, 
        &aux[conta].aluguer->estado, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->dia, 
        &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->mes, &aux[conta].aluguer->dataIn->ano);`  should always check the returned value.  So this call to `fscanf()` should be wrapped in an `if()` statement and the returned value compared with 4